# How to move from one tabbar to another programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to move from one Tabbar index to another tabbar index but it can't work. Actually i had three Tabbar index by default when application load i had shown tabbar 1.

At 0 tab index i had my account page i don't want to give direct access(without login) to my account Tabbar when anybody press Tabbar 0 then login page open at login page when user successfully logged in then i am using the following method to show first Tabbar.

```
// define the target method
-(void) targetMethod:(NSTimer *) theTimer
{
    sessId = wsobject.sessId;
    singletonOjb = [SingletonClass sharedManager];
    singletonOjb.sessId = sessId;
    singletonOjb.Username = wsobject.getname;

    if (sessId != NULL)
    {
        singletonOjb.password = password.text;
        userName.text = @"";
        password.text = @"";
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        [self storeFavObj];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //userName.text = @"";
        password.text = @"";
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: check you tabbarcontroller using NSLog . is it null or not.

Comment: <b>yes it is null</b>

Comment: how you take tabar show your code

Comment: NSLog(@"tabbar index %@",self.tabBarController);
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

Comment: Can you post code where you create tab bar controller and set the individual view controllers?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean selecting different tab bar items inside a tab bar, this is enough.

```
[tabBar setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

instead of 1 use which index u need to put